# TFTP Transfer Timed Out Centos7

Tags: linux, centos, tftp

I've been having an issue with any FTP in Linux since the dawn of its existence and everyone just tells me "Google it" or closes my thread because someone's already answered a "Similar Question" but no matter what version of Centos I use 6 or 7 i can't just type in yum install tftp xinetd and put my files in tftp directory and start using it. It never works like that and never has for me at least.

What I'm doing is setting up an installer for an application I made that is designed to work on every single arch and every single Linux system therefor it uses commands like tftp wget curl and all that to download the files required to install the application from my server.

The issue is when I setup TFTP Correctly it doesn't work
When I type in tftp  -c get  on my other server 10 seconds later it returns "Transfer timed out.". I did a bit of testing and tried using the local IP address and got the same response. But on the server that has the tftpserver it works completely fine.

```
service tftp
{
    socket_type             = dgram
    protocol                = udp
    wait                    = yes
    user                    = root
    server                  = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args             = -s -c /var/lib/tftpboot
    disable                 = no
    per_source              = 11
    cps                     = 100 2
    flags                   = IPv4
}
```

UPDATE: lsmod | grep tftp returns nothing and selinux is disabled.

Comment: Have you configured your firewall?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I think we should share information as to what our solutions are.
https://serverfault.com/questions/894903/centos-6-7-tftp-server-does-not-send-reply